# Outlook decrypt PGP message as html

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-web-addins, pgp

I've a solution where before sending emails I need to use PGP encryption.

Email encryption and decryption in outlook works just fine but the problem is that outlook decrypt pgp email as plain text and not as html template.

Is it possible to use pgp encryption on email that is html template and when decrypt it would be read as html?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which platform are you using: Outlook Desktop or Outlook Web(New/Old)?

Comment: Outlook desktop